# Android Soft Keyboard - re sizing Icon Preview

Tags: android, icons, preview, android-softkeyboard

I managed to make a Softkeyboard and also implemented flick events. Now I would like to display some feed back on the key preview which is an Icon.

Is there anyway to control the Icon preview size or maybe make some items visible/invisible on the layout?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I read in another discussion thread that you can set opacity of keyboard key images by setting the alpha value. For example, if you set `0x00RRGGBB`, then you'll get an entirely invisible image. `00` means alpha has `0` value.

Also, you might want to try and read more on Keyboard and KeyboardView in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html respectively.

Btw, I am also working on a custom IME that was based on SoftKeyboard. I wanted to implement flick events as well. How did you do yours?